# Arduino Tools > Serial Port greyed out

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am running Debian 7 (Linux Crunchbang) and wanted to use The Arduino IDE to program my Arduino UNO. To do that I installed the package `arduino`. When I started the Arduino I was asked to add my user to the `dialout` group. So I did with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout <my-username>`.

However when I start the Arduino IDE using `arduino` in the commandline the IDE opens but I am not able to load my program to the Arduino. The  error message is "Serial port COM1 not found. Did you select the right one from the Tools > Serial Port menu?" And when I went to select the Serial Port, the option "Tools > Serial Port" is greyed out.

I thought it is because I did not grant read and write permissions on my usb port (ttyACM0). So I did `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0` but the option is still greyed out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718779/arduino-nano-avrdude-ser-opensystem-cant-open-device-com1the-system/36327968#36327968

Answer (score 46):

chdmod works for my under debian (proxmox):

```
# chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

For installing arduino IDE:

```
# apt-get install arduino arduino-core arduino-mk
```

Add the user to dialout group:

```
# gpasswd -a user dialout
```

Restart Linux.

Try with the File > Examples > 01.Basic > Blink, change the 2 delays to delay(60) and click the upload button for testing on arduino, led must blink faster. ;)

Comment: I need to run these commands every time that I reboot Linux. Any idea why?

Comment: Changing the permissions of a /dev file sounds as a "good" solution but it's not. With this you are allowing any and every application access to the device, appart that is not permanent.

Comment: @Seanny123 this is why ^

Comment: In my case: sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS0

Comment: In my case: Add the user to dialout group and restart.

Comment: My case was the USB port was just enough in to give power but no USB kernel events LOL. `sudo udevadm monitor` showed me `ttyACM0` when I pushed further. no need to chmod once it was there. did `gpasswd` just in case so not sure it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

sudo arduino is the only way I get the Arduino IDE working (serial port and upload) on ubuntu 12.04 (64)
Indeed the serial port to use is /dev/ttyACM0 in my case too.
The other two (ttyS4 and ttyS0) gave an error when trying to upload to Uno.
Have fun

Comment: It works probably because you aren't added to the correct group and are running arduino as root. This will surelly give you a headache when you try to directly edit, copy, cut or delete a file, since they are owned by root. [The correct solution is adding yourself to the group and log out and in.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29068067/792066)

Comment: OMG thank you, I have literally been struggling for the past hour trying to get this to work. sudo was all that was needed

Comment: Starting the Arduino IDE from terminal together with using "sudo" solved the problem for me too. I guess it's essential that the IDE is runned with root privileges. So that it can access the driver-directory.

Comment: This answer should get accepted.
Save my day.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Try Disconnecting the usb and plugging it back in. Its only grayed out because the ide cannot find any com ports that the uno has been plugged into.

another solution is to try all the com ports and see which one works.

finally if all fails try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 3):

Close all instances of the arduino IDE
open ~/.arduino/preferences.txt and look for the line:

```
serial.port=<not your port>
```

and change it to your port:

```
serial.port=/dev/ttyACM0
```

you may have to log out for it to take effect

Answer (score 3):

If it is helpful to anyone, I had this problem using Ubuntu 22.04. The issue stemmed from:

- **apparmor** (apparmor denied error, logging with dmesg)
- **brltty** (ch34x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0)

Solved it by removing both:

- https://www.simplified.guide/ubuntu/remove-apparmor
- sudo apt remove brltty

*You can disable apparmor and it should work, however this made applications like firefox useless. My recomendation would be to totally remove it*

Answer (score 2):

open $arduinoHome/arduino in text editor and modify last string:

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base "$@"
```

to

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts="/dev/ttyACMN" processing.app.Base "$@"
```

(set property gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts to /dev/ttyACMN,where ttyACMN is name of serial port which you use)

it may temporary fix bug in rxtx library. helped me to upload sketch with arduino1.0.5 IDE.

Maybe would helpful for someone.

Comment: How to open open $arduinoHome/arduino in text editor?

Comment: (win)By context menu -> "open with..." or 
(linux) from terminal something like `gedit $arduinoHome/arduino`

Answer (score 2):

In my case this turned out to be a bad USB hub.

The 'lsusb' command can be used to display all recognized devices. If the unit is not plugged in the option to set the speed will be disabled.

The lsusb command should output something like the string 'Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Bridge(I2C/SPI/UART/FIFO)' if your device is recognized. Mine was an RFDuino

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved this issue by uninstalling the version of Arduino that I installed via `apt-get` and instead installed via the [official website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software).

With the latest version of Arduino I didn't have the problem described on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

> So I did with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout <my-username>`.

You need to log out after you add yourself to a group so those changes are applied. Just log out and log in again and the menu should be available.

Answer (score 1):

install rx-tx lib for java run this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java -y
```

output port

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER 
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

help regconize usb device

Answer (score 1):

I solved following serial port related problems in ubuntu 18.04 as follows:

**Problem 1 :  Cannot open /dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied**
Solution  :  Grant permissions to read/write to the serial port with this terminal command --->  `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`
Here replace tty port with your respective ubuntu port.

**Problem 2 : Failed to open /dev/ttyACM0 (port busy)**
Solution  : This problem appears when serial port is busy or already occupied. So kill the busy serial port with command ---> `fuser -k /dev/ttyACM0`. Here replace tty port with your respective ubuntu port.

**Problem 3 : Board at /dev/ttyACM0 is not available**
Solution : In this case your serial port in tools menu will be greyed out. I googled a lot for this, but I none of  solution worked for me. Atlast I tried different arduino board and usb connector and it was working for me. So, if you are having old arduino board (can be solved using required drivers) or defected arduino board then only this problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps install the IDE and remove the error `java.lang.NullPointerException thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver` which usually comes with arduino installed with `apt-get` command in Ubuntu.

**Install the IDE**

```
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

**for removing java error in IDE**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

This also shows the **Serial Port** which was grayed out due to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Same comment as Philip Kirkbride. 
It wasn't a permission  issue, but using the Arduino IDE downloaded from their website solved my problem.
Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with which I struggled for few days, reading all the blog posts, watching videos and finally after i **changed my uno board**, it worked perfectly well. But **before I did that**, there were a few things I tried, which I think also had an effect.

- Extracted the files to opt folder, change the preference --> behavior --> executable text files --> ask what to do. After that, double clicked arduino on the folder, selected run by terminal
- added user dialout like described in other answers.

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score -1):

For a Windows solution I've found that disabling and re-enabling the Arduino in Device Manager, then restarting the Arduino IDE does the trick without fail (no unplugging necessary). Why this error occurs in the first place is beyond me. Perhaps the corresponding method for Linux will fix your problem.

Slightly related (not really), I had an issue with an AVR board a while back which was fixed by setting the device to a new COM port in the driver settings. Again, however you linux bunnies do it, I'm sure it'll be cookies and cream.

Cheers brother,

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue. My solution was to install and use java7:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select the number referring to the java-7 path.

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't have the correct permissions. Try adding yourself to these groups.

```
sudo adduser username ttyl
sudo adduser username serial
sudo adduser username uucp
```

Then restart your system and check if you got added to the groups.

```
groups username
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try to run as an administrator...
Run terminal, type sudo arduino, type your root password, and... :)