# hey, I have a problem with uploading the code to my arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

every time i want to upload the code i got the same error:
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM5"
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

I tried every think I shecked the port and the version of arduino I changed the USB cable I reinstall the COM drivers I reinstall the IDE but got the same erreur. and now I have doubt that my arduino is broken but I still got the red light like always

Comment: Did you try all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718779/arduino-nano-avrdude-ser-opensystem-cant-open-device-com1-the-sys?rq=2)?

Comment: yes but it did not work